# Submitted data is not showing in the page processor

Tags: php, jquery, var-dump

I have an url that post data to another page (`page_processor.php`)

The content of `page_processor.php` is:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST($email));
?>
```

When I run my code, it doesn't show any data.

I tried `print_r("$_REQUEST(email)",true);` but have the same result.

I also tried:

```
<?php
var_dump($_REQUEST($email[]));
?>
```

Again not data is being captured.

The posted url is: `https://www.example.com/submit-form-page/?email=email1%40test.com&email=email2%40test.com`

The form is:

```
<form id="test_form" action="https://www.example.com/submit-form-page/">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div id="input_wrapper"></div>
        <button id="save_btn" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
        <button id="add_btn" class="btn btn-primary">Add Email</button>
      </div>
</form>
```

And there is a jQuery script to handle the form:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-2Pmvv0kuTBOenSvLm6bvfBSSHrUJ+3A7x6P5Ebd07/g=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var x = 0;
    $('#save_btn').hide();
  
    $('#add_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    appendRow(); // append new element to form 
    x++; // increment counter for form
    $('#save_btn').show(); // show save button for form
  });

    $('#input_wrapper').on('click', '.deleteBtn', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id = e.currentTarget.id; // set the id based on the event 'e'
    $('div[id='+id+']').remove(); //find div based on id and remove
    x--; // decrement the counter for form.
    
    if (x === 0) { 
        $('#save_btn').hide(); // hides the save button if counter is equal to zero
    }
  });
    
  $('#save_btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = $('#test_form').serializeObject(); // serialize the form
    var obj; //obj can be use to send to ajax call
    if(Array.isArray(formData.email)) {
        for(var i = 0; i < formData.email.length; i++) {
        obj = {};
        // set the obj for submission
        obj.email= formData.email[i];
        // This object could be push into an array
        console.log('object from form array ', obj);
        $('form#test_form').submit();
      };
    } else {
        obj = {};
      obj.email = formData.email;
      console.log('single obj from form ', obj);
    }
    $('form#test_form').submit();
  });
  
  function appendRow() {
    $('#input_wrapper').append(
        '<div id="'+x+'" class="form-group" style="display:flex;">' +
          '<div>' +
            '<input type="text" id="'+x+'" class="form-control" name="email"                                    placeholder="Add Email"/>' +
          '</div>' +
          
          '<div>'+
            '<button id="'+x+'" class="btn btn-danger deleteBtn"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></button>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>');
  }
});

$.fn.serializeObject = function(asString) {
   var o = {};
   var a = this.serializeArray();
   $.each(a, function() {

       if($('#' + this.name).hasClass('date')) {
           this.value = new Date(this.value).setHours(12);
       }

       if (o[this.name] !== undefined) {
           if (!o[this.name].push) {
               o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
           }
           o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
       } else {
           o[this.name] = this.value || '';
       }
   });
   if (asString) {
       return JSON.stringify(o);
   }
   return o;
};
</script>
```

What I am trying to do is to create a form in PHP then post it's data to another php page.

The jQuery function is to create multiple textboxes dynamically then submit the data to the processor page.

I tried everything and can't figure out what is wrong.

**Edit**: I moved

```
$('form#test_form').submit();
```

outside the loop.

What is wrong?

Thank you

Comment: What do you see in `var_dump($_REQUEST)`?

Comment: There's no `email` input in the form. Where is `formData.email` supposed to come from?

Comment: @Barmar array(1) { ["email"]=> string(15) "email2@test.com" }

Comment: @Barmar the email inputbox is created daynamically by jQuery

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius var dump is all the code I have in the page....I am trying to see if the page is catching the submited data by url then I will build my code. Once var dump catch all emails....it will be very easy for me to continue developing my php script.

Comment: I don't understand what your JS for the save button is trying to do. It fills in `formData` and `obj`, but doesn't use them when submitting. It makes no sense to call `form.submit()` inside a loop, because submitting the form reloads the page.

Comment: For book-keeping fields, use input type=hidden , and try to get it work w/o ajax first, then you can add jquery on top, it's easy.

Comment: @Barmar I can fix the submit form command and put it outside the loop...but for now I think I need to modify the name of the fields to `obj.email[] = formData.email[i];` and the inputbox name to `email[]`, but I don't know how to do this

Comment: You are modifying the searilization, not the form. But then submit the form. This just does not compute (if I could decipher your massive amount of code that fast precisely enough).

Comment: Just change `name="email"` to `name="email[]"`. When you submit the form, PHP will automatically convert `$_REQUEST{'email']` to an array.

Comment: You don't need any of the JavaScript for processing the save button.

Comment: @Barmar I changed to `name="email[]"` but I am getting JS error **Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #email[]** I think I need to change something also in JS

Comment: that's a bug in your `serializeObject()` function, it assumes the name and ID will be the same. It will never work correctly for forms that have inputs with the same name.

Comment: for the selector: name != id (#) -- again Barmar was first. You should read why they comment, they also parse your code better than I do.

Comment: Unless you really need the part of the function that reformats `class="date"` inputs, you can just get rid of that part of the function.

Comment: But I still don't understand why you're calling `serializeObject()` in the first place. You're not using AJAX to send the form.

Comment: And if you do want to switch to AJAX, you can just use the standard `.serialize()`. What is all this confusing code for?

Comment: @Barmar `var formData = $('#test_form').serializeArray();`  fixed my problem in addition to ading `name=email[]` Thank you all for your help